# Unable to render directive template properly in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the directive

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/components/event/event.html",
    scope: {index: '@'},
    controller: "eventCtrl"
  };
};
```

The code for controller

```
module.exports = ($scope)=>{
  console.log($scope.index);
  $scope.loadDetails = ()=>{
    console.log("hello there");
  }
};
```

and for template

```
.event
  h3(ng-bind="index.title")
  p(ng-bind="index.description")
  .price(ng-show="index.is_paid") {{cost}} $
  a.button-primary(ng-click="loadDetails()") Details
```

The problem is the variables are not being rendered in the template. I tested if it is being passed correctly using `console.log` and i am getting proper response. Also the function `loadDetails()` is working properly leading me to believe that there is not problem with setting up the controller. Where exactly am i going wrong ?

Comment: the console log is stamp them as string?

Comment: cause @ .. don't is for string value?

Comment: Its json object

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi okay now i think i am getting somewhere, i can't reference field inside index. I think you are right about the string thing, what should i use instead ?

Comment: Try to use = insted of @

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi finally got it working thanks... Place an answer will accept it :)

Comment: done...realy thnx!!..and happy to helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your  `scope: {index: '@'},` cause @ mean it is for `string` ..so try with :

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/components/event/event.html",
    scope: {index: '='},
    controller: "eventCtrl"
  };
};
```